# Image Retrain Inception only check the own specific category not tensor dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have retrained the inception model from my data set of traffic sign.Its working fine but when I am trying to check other image e.g panda it's resulting with the name of traffic sign with some probabilities.I don't understand why its doing it.I need both tensor-flow data-set and my own category too.
My steps:

- I have installed the python 3.5.2 in windows 7
- I installed tensor-flow with 
  `pip --install tensorflow`
- I download these two files retrain.py to train my data and label_image.py to check image.

Files downloaded from:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining

Comment: Fixed list formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood the fundamentals of transfer learning wrt this image retraining program.

In the image retraining program you are referencing, you are taking the inception CNN model that is already pretraining on the imageNET dataset. You are then retraining the final classification layers on your NEW classes and data.

The transfer learning occurs because you are retaining all the learnt feature extraction filters etc. in the early layers and you are just reclassifying the activations of those layers to new classes based on your new dataset. This means you are replacing the classification part with a new one. AFAIK there is no way to simply add classes to a CNN model via transfer learning because you have already trained a softmax layer (for example) with the classification distribution for each class.

To achieve what you are suggesting will require you to retrain the final layers of inception with the original dataset PLUS your additional data. This will take a long time due to the size of imageNET.

I would re-evaluate whether you actually need to be able to utilise all these classes in your application or whether it is sufficient to just have your traffic signs etc.

You can learn more about the program at the [tensorflow tutorial here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining#training_on_your_own_categories)

Comment: got it thanks.Can you suggest any solution for this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942587/save-image-of-detected-object-from-image-using-tensor-flow